# SubSonic 2.2 Class Generation

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic2.2

I am using SubSonic on a project with many tables which were created by a sourcecode generator. I noticed Some classes created by SubSonic were generated without code and have the folowing message

```
The class...was not generated because ... does not have a primary key.
```

Is there any way for me to get the code to be generated without adding keyes to all the tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add primary key to table. You can create an auto-increment int field as primary key.

This happens with almost every database layer code generator, because without primary key it cannot generate edit/delete functionality.

Answer (score 0):

SubSonic requires primary keys on tables to generate its code.

From the documentation: http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Conventions

> Primary Keys
>
> If you want to use SubSonic to access your table, you need to have a Primary Key defined for your table. This is good practice in every case and we need it to do certain things with your table. If you don't have a Primary Key defined, your class won't be generated.
>
> If you don't believe us, or if you think this is a silly convention - SubSonic isn't for you.